# How to configure plugin.xml for IOS plugin upgrade from 2.x to 3.0 in cordova / phonegap

Tags: javascript, xcode, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

I am trying to use a phonegap 2.9 plugin in 3.0 . I am making a plugin.xml to comply with plugman. Apart from adding the header and source file in plugin.xml (.m & .h ) the instructions for the old plugin say the following (after the jump) .  My question is what do i put in my plugin.xml to create a outputLibrary folder like mentioned below containing the .a file

---

Ensure that an outputLibrary folder exists in the folder structure under Plugins. For the outputLibrary in Xcode, you must select “Create folder references for any added folders” as shown in Figure 6.

[image]
Figure 6: Adding outputLibrary to Plugins folder in Xcode

7. Ensure that the include folder exists under outputLibrary folder in Plugins. If it is not there add it, for example, outputLibrary/include.

￼￼
￼￼8. Add the following native file to the include folder under outputLibrary as shown in Figure 5.  libATTiosPhonegapPlugin.a

Comment: if your using cordova 3.0 you just need to install plugin through plugman it will make sure everything in place for plugin...

Comment: @SathyaRaj this plugin does not support 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, on cordova 3.0 you can still install the plugins the same way you did on phonegap 2.9, manually.

Second, a link to the plugin might help.

About the plugin.xml, to add the .a file you should use the framework option:

```
<source-file src="pathToTheLibFile/libATTiosPhonegapPlugin.a" framework="true" />
```

But AFAIK, you can't specify the “Create folder references for any added folders” option on the config.xml, so do the manual install as you did on 2.9

EDIT:

Looking at the plugin it doesn't seem to really need the “Create folder references for any added folders” option. try creating the plugin.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin xmlns="http://www.phonegap.com/ns/plugins/1.0"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    id="org.att.phonegap.plugin.AttPlugin"
    version="1.0.0">

    <name>AttPlugin</name>
  <author>AT&T</author>

  <description>
   AT&T Plugin
  </description>

  <license>AT&T License</license>

  <js-module src="plugins/ios/js/lib/att.js" name="AttPlugin">
      <clobbers target="AttPlugin" />
  </js-module>

  <engines>
      <engine name="cordova" version="&gt;=3.0.0" />
  </engines>

    <platform name="ios">
        <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
          <feature name="AttPlugin">
            <param name="ios-package" value="org.att.phonegap.plugin.AttPlugin"/>
          </feature>
        </config-file>

        <source-file src="plugins/ios/nativeplugin/ATTPhonegapHelper.m" />
        <source-file src="plugins/ios/nativeplugin/outputLibrary/libATTiOSPhonegapPlugin.a" framework="true" />

        <header-file src="plugins/ios/nativeplugin/outputLibrary/include/ATTiOSPhonegapPlugin/ATTPluginHTTPRequest.h" />
        <header-file src="plugins/ios/nativeplugin/outputLibrary/include/ATTiOSPhonegapPlugin/ATTiOSPhonegapPlugin.h" />
        <header-file src="plugins/ios/nativeplugin/outputLibrary/include/ATTiOSPhonegapPlugin/InAppMessagePlugin.h" />
        <header-file src="plugins/ios/nativeplugin/outputLibrary/include/ATTiOSPhonegapPlugin/MMSPlugin.h" />
        <header-file src="plugins/ios/nativeplugin/outputLibrary/include/ATTiOSPhonegapPlugin/SpeechPlugin.h" />
        <header-file src="plugins/ios/nativeplugin/outputLibrary/include/ATTiOSPhonegapPlugin/TTSPlugin.h" />
        <header-file src="plugins/ios/nativeplugin/ATTPhonegapHelper.h" />
    </platform>
</plugin>
```

Not sure about this part because you might need to add some other js files

```
<js-module src="plugins/ios/js/lib/att.js" name="AttPlugin">
      <clobbers target="AttPlugin" />
  </js-module>
```

Comment: This is the plugin i am trying to use https://github.com/attdevsupport/ATT_APIPlatform_PhoneGap      Are you aware of any changes to the manual installation method for 3.0 .. Anything that needs to be done differently?